# How to start a new XSession from same Ubuntu machine from systemd service

Tags: ubuntu, x11, systemd

I need to run google-chrome on a server as a service, and it needs Xsession, which is accessed and created by xrdp. The hosting party restart the whole server weekly. I created systemd services for everything else, but I can't find a solution for creating a new Xsession after boot.

If we connect, and disconnect with RDP client, it creates a new xsession and it's working fine.

Ubuntu 16.04
xrdp service

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you cannot start an XSession without a graphical session.
You need an existing XSession (dummy on the same machine, or an other existing XSession on an other linux box, or a windows machine), so you can RDP.

(I created a service, which at boot called an API, that RDP-d back to the machine, and all the other dependent service had to have a serious delay at the startup script.)